# React-Redux - State object update, re-render the components but the change isn't pass to the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im working on a calendar app using React and Redux.
The calendar app fetch dates and their events from google api, so users could see their google calendars.
In the debugger i can see that the data is ok all the way from the dispatch to the render function. the only problem is that the component inside (MonthlyCalendar) that gets the events getting an empty object.
when not using redux and instead just react state, the component do get the new props with the updated events object.
I added console.log to each life cycle of the component.

When using redux i get this: [image]

using regular state (not redux):

[image]

i don't know what I'm missing with redux flow but when debugging it's shown that render is executed with the updated state events,
still the console.log print empty.

The code from dispatch to render :

**Dispatch**

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'message',
      e => {
        if (e.data && e.data.data) {

          dispatch(connectBtnClicked(e.data.data));

        }
      },
      false,
    );
    if (isFirstRun.current) {
      isFirstRun.current = false;
      return;
    }
  }, [])
```

**Action**

```
export const connectBtnClicked = (userName: string) => (dispatch: any) => {
  const urlArray = [
    'https://calendar-server.codev.co.il/getEvents',
    'https://calendar-server.codev.co.il/getCalendarsListIds',
    'https://calendar-server.codev.co.il/getSettings',
  ];
  const requestsArray = urlArray.map(url => {
    const request = new Request(url, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'GET',
    });

    return fetch(request).then(res => res.json());
  });
  Promise.all(requestsArray).then(allResults => {
    console.log('***allResults', allResults);
    dispatch({
      type: CONNECT_BTN_CLICKED,
      payload: {
        isConnect: true,
        userName,
        dates: allResults[0].eventsByDates,
        calendarsList: allResults[1].calendarsList,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
  CONNECT_BTN_CLICKED,
  SET_COMP_ID,
  DISCONNECT_BTN_CLICKED,
  CONNECT_ERROR,
} from '../actions/actionType';

const initState = {
  isConnect: false,
  isDisconnect: false,
  isSettingsLoaded: false,
  userName: '',
  isLoader: false,
  connectError: false,
  statusCode: '',
  dates: {},
  calendarsList: [],
};

export default (state = initState, action: any) => {
  console.log('setReducer', action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_COMP_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        compId: action.payload,
      };
    case CONNECT_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        connectEtsyError: action.payload.err,
        statusCode: action.payload.statusCode,
      };
    case CONNECT_BTN_CLICKED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isConnect: action.payload.isConnect,
        userName: action.payload.userName,
        dates: action.payload.dates,
        calendarsList: action.payload.calendarsList,
        isSettingsLoaded: true,
      };
    case DISCONNECT_BTN_CLICKED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isConnect: false,
        // isDisconnect: action.payload,
        dates: {},
        calendarsList: [],
        userName: '',
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Root Reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
//@ts-ignore
import settings from './settingsReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  settings,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

**Provider Wrapping App.js Component**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import App from './components/App/App';
// import App from './components/App';
import i18n from './i18n';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './components/settings/store';
const locale = window.__LOCALE__;
const baseURL = window.__BASEURL__;


fedopsLogger.appLoaded();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Please wait...</div>}>
      <Router>
        {/* <ExperimentsProvider options={{ experiments }}> */}
        <App />
        {/* </ExperimentsProvider> */}
      </Router>
    </React.Suspense>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**App.js render - MonthlyCalendar is  the events receiving component**

```
render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    const events = this.props.events;
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/index"
          render={() => (
            <MonthlyCalendar
              weekStarter={this.state.weekStarter}
              events={events}
              handleMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
              isTimeZoneShown={this.state.isTimeZoneShown}
              isTimeShown={this.state.isTimeShown}
              locale={this.state.locale}
              //timeZone={this.state.timeZone}
              isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={this.state.isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/settings"
          render={() => (
            <Settings
              fetchEvents={this.fetchEvents}
              initialState={"this.props.initialState"}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/mobile"
          render={() => (
            <MonthlyCalendar
              weekStarter={this.state.weekStarter}
              events={events}
              handleMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
              isTimeZoneShown={this.state.isTimeZoneShown}
              isTimeShown={this.state.isTimeShown}
              locale={this.state.locale}
              isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={this.state.isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({});
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  isConnect: state.settings.isConnect,
  userName: state.settings.userName,
  events: state.settings.dates,
  calendarsList: state.settings.calendarsList,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withTranslation()(withEnhancedStyleLoader(App)));
```

**There is not setState in componentDidMount or any other method in App.js I removed it all, so only props change could re-render**

**Edit 1**
i dropped all the HOCS and still in render i see the updated events, but the child component print empty events.

**Render on events received**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

the child component only render once. even when events props is updated, and re-render MonthlyCalendar( the child component ) doesn't re-render. I tried:

```
const events = {...this.props.events};
```

also:

```
const events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(this.props.events);
```

didn't work...

**EDIT 3 - MonthlyCalendar Component**

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    console.log('[constructor] props.events: ',props.events)
    const timezone = moment.tz.guess();
    const dateObject = moment().tz(timezone, true);
    this.state = {
      dateObject,
      timezone,
      isTimezonesOpen: false,
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('[shouldComponentUpdate] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    return true
  }
```

....

```
getCalendar() {
    const { events } = this.props;
    const { dateObject } = this.state;
    const beforeFillers = this.getMonthBeforFillers(dateObject, events);
    const days = this.getDays(dateObject, events);
    const afterFillers = this.hasAfterFillers(beforeFillers, days) ?
      this.getAfterMonthFillers(dateObject, events) : {};
    return { days, beforeFillers, afterFillers };
  }



async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('[componentDidUpdate] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    this.props.locale !== prevProps.locale && await this.updateLocale();
  }

  updateLocale = async () => {
    const { locale, i18n } = this.props;
    await i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
    moment.locale(locale);
    const { timezone, dateObject } = this.state;
    const dateObjectToSet = moment(dateObject.format()).tz(timezone, true);
    this.setState({ dateObject: dateObjectToSet });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('[componentDidMount] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    this.props.locale !== 'en' && await this.updateLocale();
  }

  render() {
    const { t, weekStarter, isTodayButtonStyleSeconday, isTimeZoneShown, isTimeShown } = this.props;
    const { dateObject, timezone, isTimezonesOpen } = this.state;
    const { days, beforeFillers, afterFillers } = this.getCalendar();
    const month = dateObject.format(t('Google_Calendar_Picker_Month'));
    const timezoneSelected = moment().tz(timezone).format(t('Google_Calendar_Timezone_Selected'));
    const timezoneSelectedTitle = t('Google_Calendar_Timezone_Selected_Title', { timezoneSelected });
    console.log('[render] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    return (
      <TPAComponentsProvider value={{ mobile: false, rtl: false }}>
        <div className={classes.MonthlyCalendar}>
          <CalendarControllers
            isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            todayClicked={this.todayClickedHander}
            onPreviousClicked={() => this.timePickerClickedHandler(false)}
            timeToDisplay={month}
            onNextClicked={() => this.timePickerClickedHandler(true)}
            onTimezoneChange={this.timezoneChangeHandler}
            timezone={timezoneSelectedTitle}
            isTimezonesOpen={isTimezonesOpen}
            openTimezones={this.openTimezones}
            closeTimezones={this.closeTimezones}
            isTimeZoneShown={isTimeZoneShown}
          />
          <MonthTable
            weekStarter={weekStarter}
            days={days}
            beforeFillers={beforeFillers}
            dateObject={dateObject}
            afterFillers={afterFillers}
            renderCell={(
              time: any,
              events: any,
              cellRef: any,
              handleEventClick: any,
              setExpendedEvent: any,
              expendedEvent: any,
              isOutsideClicked: any,
            ) => (
                <MonthlyCell
                  events={events}
                  handleEventClick={handleEventClick}
                  time={time}
                  cellRef={cellRef}
                  expendedEvent={expendedEvent}
                  isOutsideClicked={isOutsideClicked}
                  setExpendedEvent={setExpendedEvent}
                  isTimeShown={isTimeShown}
                />
              )}
          />
        </div>
      </TPAComponentsProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(MonthlyCalendar);
```

**EDIT 4**

after searching for solutions i added key to the div of MonthlyCalendar and also i added destructor {...this.props.events}. still no re-render
Following is the updated MonthlyCalendar:

```
getCalendar() {
    const mutableEvents = {...this.props.events};
    const { dateObject } = this.state;
    const beforeFillers = this.getMonthBeforFillers(dateObject, mutableEvents);
    const days = this.getDays(dateObject, mutableEvents);
    const afterFillers = this.hasAfterFillers(beforeFillers, days) ?
      this.getAfterMonthFillers(dateObject, mutableEvents) : {};
    return { days, beforeFillers, afterFillers };
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('[componentDidUpdate] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    this.props.locale !== prevProps.locale && await this.updateLocale();
  }

  updateLocale = async () => {
    const { locale, i18n } = this.props;
    await i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
    moment.locale(locale);
    const { timezone, dateObject } = this.state;
    const dateObjectToSet = moment(dateObject.format()).tz(timezone, true);
    this.setState({ dateObject: dateObjectToSet });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('[componentDidMount] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    this.props.locale !== 'en' && await this.updateLocale();
  }

  render() {
    const { t, weekStarter, isTodayButtonStyleSeconday, isTimeZoneShown, isTimeShown, events: propEvents } = this.props;
    const eventsKey = Object.keys(propEvents).length;
    const { dateObject, timezone, isTimezonesOpen } = this.state;
    const { days, beforeFillers, afterFillers } = this.getCalendar();
    const month = dateObject.format(t('Google_Calendar_Picker_Month'));
    const timezoneSelected = moment().tz(timezone).format(t('Google_Calendar_Timezone_Selected'));
    const timezoneSelectedTitle = t('Google_Calendar_Timezone_Selected_Title', { timezoneSelected });
    console.log('[render] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    return (
      <TPAComponentsProvider value={{ mobile: false, rtl: false }}>
        <div key={eventsKey} className={classes.MonthlyCalendar}>
          <CalendarControllers
            isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            todayClicked={this.todayClickedHander}
            onPreviousClicked={() => this.timePickerClickedHandler(false)}
            timeToDisplay={month}
            onNextClicked={() => this.timePickerClickedHandler(true)}
            onTimezoneChange={this.timezoneChangeHandler}
            timezone={timezoneSelectedTitle}
            isTimezonesOpen={isTimezonesOpen}
            openTimezones={this.openTimezones}
            closeTimezones={this.closeTimezones}
            isTimeZoneShown={isTimeZoneShown}
          />
          <MonthTable
            weekStarter={weekStarter}
            days={days}
            beforeFillers={beforeFillers}
            dateObject={dateObject}
            afterFillers={afterFillers}
            renderCell={(
              time: any,
              events: any,
              cellRef: any,
              handleEventClick: any,
              setExpendedEvent: any,
              expendedEvent: any,
              isOutsideClicked: any,
            ) => (
                <MonthlyCell
                  events={events}
                  handleEventClick={handleEventClick}
                  time={time}
                  cellRef={cellRef}
                  expendedEvent={expendedEvent}
                  isOutsideClicked={isOutsideClicked}
                  setExpendedEvent={setExpendedEvent}
                  isTimeShown={isTimeShown}
                />
              )}
          />
        </div>
      </TPAComponentsProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(MonthlyCalendar);
```

Comment: Not sure what's the issue, but I tried creating a simple example with react-thunk and some mocked async actions and it seems to be working okay: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-meitner-irqhu 
It could be your other HOCs you're using on App, but can't say for sure.

Comment: @RosenDimov Hi Rosen, I'll try to look at the HOC... maybe it's something there. thx

Comment: @RosenDimov can you check my second edit ?

Comment: Try to remove `return` from `useEffect` in **Dispatch**.

Comment: Hm, I see you render exactly the same thing for /index and /mobile paths. If that's the case, you can join them in a single route passing array of paths to <Route> like ```path={]"/index", "/mobile"]}``` Not sure if that would help, but I just noticed it. Also, do you have any optimizations for MonthlyCalendar component (```shouldComponentUpdate``` or ```React.memo```)? Are you at on of those two routes when <App> updates?

Comment: @RosenDimov tried it didn't do the magic. Im pretty sure is about React not seeing the events object updated in the child component. I saw some solutions so now Im adding in the child {...this.props.events} and also key: <div className="Monthly" key={Object.keys(this.props.events).length} />. but i dont now it sounds weird that the component doesn't update when the last object was empty

Comment: @RosenDimov no optimizations and yes im on the route because i see the calendar, just the events are missing and only when using the redux state

Comment: Hm, I can't see anything wrong with the App component, at least. Can you show a part of the MonthlyCalendar component - its definition and the place where you display the events?

Comment: @RosenDimov EDIT 3

Comment: So even ```shouldComponentUpdate``` is not called after changes in state of App?

Comment: @RosenDimov yes, shouldComponentUpdate doesn't called, nothing is called when events get updated. it gets mounted and that's it.

Comment: Yeah, I think ```shouldComponentUpdate``` is not called when the component initially mounts, but ```componentDidMount``` should be called. And inside ```componentDidMount``` you get again an empty object?

Comment: @RosenDimov yes, shouldComponent isn't called on first life cycle and componentDidMount() is called with empty events.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, but can you show some part of the withTranslation HOC? And btw normally the component shouldn't re-mount if you're on the same route all the time even if state changes in App. I tried that on the simple example I provided in my first comment.

Comment: @RosenDimov withTranslation is part of i18n-react library, it's not the problem. I added another edit with the updated MonthlyCalendar, with key in it's div and destractor for events. now the component do re-render but still with empty object.

Comment: no it's not re-render even my mistake... maybe it's the route as you said. but it's weird why react component state change will re-render but redux won't

Comment: it's not that :( maybe this would help:i see that DISCONNECT action that set events to empty object, do execute re-render of MonthlyCalendar. why empty object re-render and full object not

Comment: Then I'd suggest you try to build up incrementally what you have (by creating a mocked backend instead the real one), and by using my sample at the beginning to verify if it's really a problem with React.

Comment: @RosenDimov co-worker send me this article about the route maybe it's there https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4067 , thx for your help Rosen :)

Comment: No problems. Good look with it and I'd be happy to hear what the issue was. ;)